# android emulator memory options stop my app from running

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I seem to be having major problems with my eclipse emulator and don't know if it's the ram size or my code. In my opinion, my code should run, as it does so in my java netbeans project.

Everytime I run my application and push the connect button, I want to get the string that the server sends back and then do something with it. I have a "Process Connection" method that reads in the string, but when I return it and actually use what is being returned, my emulator crashes

My code is as follows:

```
  package za.nmmu.wrap302.networks.example02;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
 import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
  import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView lstMessages;
private EditText txtMessage;

private ArrayList<String> messages;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String message = "";
private ServerConnection connection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get references to View objects
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    lstMessages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMessages);

    // set up adapter
    messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);
    lstMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    // attach event listener
    txtMessage.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                try {
                    onTxtMessageEnterPressed();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void onBtnConnectClicked(View view) {
    clearMessages();
    connection = new ServerConnection();
    connection.start();
}

public void onTxtMessageEnterPressed() throws IOException {
    if (connection != null) {
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
        txtMessage.getText().clear();
        connection.sendData(message);
    }
}

public void addMessage(String message) {
    adapter.add(message);
}

public void clearMessages() {
    adapter.clear();
}

// the thread that will be communicating with the server
public class ServerConnection extends Thread {
    // the I/O streams that will be receiving/sending data from/to the
    // server
    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;

    private Socket client;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Step 1: Create a Socket to make connection
            connectToServer();

            // Step 2: Get the input and output streams
            getStreams();

            // Step 3: Process connection
            processConnection();


            // Step 4: Close connection
            //closeConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("CONNECTION", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void addMessage(final String message) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.addMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }

    private void connectToServer() throws IOException {
        addMessage("Attempting connection\n");
        client = new Socket("10.0.0.7", 5001);
        addMessage("Connected to: " + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
    }

    private void getStreams() throws IOException {
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        input = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        addMessage("Got I/O streams");
    }

           //I would like to call the message below and return it to anywhere else in the code 

    private String processConnection() throws IOException 
    {       
        do {
            try {
                message = (String) input.readObject();
                addMessage(message);
                return message;

            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) 
            {
                addMessage("ERROR: Unknown object type received");
            }
            return message;
        } while (!message.equals("SERVER>>> TERMINATE"));
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {
        try {
            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush();
            addMessage("CLIENT>>>" + message);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            addMessage("ERROR: Error writing object");
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        addMessage("Closing connection");
        output.close();
        input.close();
        client.close();
    }

}
}
```

My application seems to just crash whenever I call the processConnection method from anywhere.
My server picks up that I've sent the message, but my client doesn't read.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNu7m.png

My logcat shows:

```
 06-13 08:18:00.460: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 45K, 4% free 3076K/3204K, paused 293ms, total 296ms
 06-13 08:18:00.460: I/dalvikvm-heap(1145): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.687MB for 635812-byte allocation
06-13 08:18:00.530: D/dalvikvm(1145): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 3695K/3828K, paused 55ms, total 55ms
 06-13 08:18:02.220: I/Choreographer(1145): Skipped 172 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-13 08:18:02.240: D/gralloc_goldfish(1145): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-13 08:18:03.100: I/Choreographer(1145): Skipped 198 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-13 08:18:27.660: E/InputEventSender(1145): Exception dispatching finished signal.
06-13 08:18:27.660: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1145): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
```

Does the ram in the emulator affect this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dear please post your entire Logcat

Comment: You can test if the source of the problem is with the ADT emulator, by using a whole different emulator and checking whether the problem still exists. For this, I'd recommend you to try Genymotion (I'm not affiliated with them...) as it generally performs better than the "stock" emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Async task to spawn off uploading to a different thread. Android works on a single thread model and using the same thread to make HTTPRequest can result in FATAL exception. Create an Async task and spawn off the upload to it.

```
AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
runner.execute(<pass the required parameters here for file upload>);

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Call the function to upload the file here

        }
```

This is what the logcat is telling you by Main thread is doing too many tasks.

Comment: Would it be incorrect to put my entire ProcessConnection method in a run() method (which extends runnable) and just run that thread each time I need to return the received string from the server? Otherwise how would I put my ProcessConnection in an AsyncTaskRunner class? Your answer makes sense, but I'm a little confused as to how I would apply it to my code.

Comment: Yes you can put your entire processConnection method in a run method and invoke it using Async class.